# can you recommend a good debug strategy for a node express api deployed on azure?

Tags: node.js, azure, express

I've created a Node Express API and it works as expected locally.  For example, the following url returns all of the users from the DB as expected:

http://localhost:3000/users

I've deployed this Node Express API to Azure and I tried the same uri but the following message is returned:

> Cannot GET /users

How can I debug the root cause of this issue with an API deployed to Azure?  More info:  If I try to GET a uri that hasn't been configured in my *local* environment like:

http://localhost:3000/users2

Then I get a similar error message:

> Cannot GET /users2

Does an Express API server provide some type of uri which can be used to display a Swagger-type page which lists all of the available endpoints?   Looking for debug steps or insight as to why I'm not able to access a deployed endpoint that works as expected locally.  Also, what kind of logging strategy do you recommend for an Express API deployed to Azure?  For example, my API currently just logs like this:

```
app.get('/suppliers/', cors(), function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('get verb was hit');
});
```

This outputs the message to the local command window where I spun up the API using "node app.js" but how can I see this output for an API deployed to Azure?  Also, how can I view info related to unhandled exceptions for an Node Express API running on Azure?

I've enabled Application Logging for the API via the "App Service logs" left nav item.  I navigated to my API App Service in the Azure portal and selected the "Log stream" option in the left navigation pane.  This option displays a console log view in the right panel which would appear to provide relevant logging info for the associated API App Service.  However, when I submit a GET request for the API, no info is written out to the Log stream.  The Log stream console simply says "No new trace in the past 1 min(s)"

I even have the most basic status check which does nothing but simply return text to indicate that the API is responding:

```
app.get('/status', (req, res) => res.send('Working!'));
```

However, even this request results in the following output to the browser:

> Cannot GET /status

And no additional info is written out to the Azure App Service Log stream for the API.

Comment: "remote debugging" --- I've never had to do it, but I imagine it's possible to remotely debug your application in vscode or chrome just like you would an app running on localhost, although if your app is in "production" mode then it will likely not have the debugging turned on.  you my also not realize you can "attach to process" for a lot of applications, like node or a C# application.

Comment: Assuming that the app has been deployed to a Windows WebApp, I'd suggest first checking if node.exe is running from Process Explorer from Kudu site. If that's not running, check the web.config file for issue: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/node-todo/blob/master/web.config